# Fatality Rate for SARS-CoV-2

Tags: dataset, epidemiology

I am sure many people have been reviewing the data about the SARS-CoV-2 epidemic. One of my main sources is at [Worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/). My question is geared toward a specific statistic they provide, namely the recovered/discharged versus deaths for closed cases.

Although there is currently some variability in the estimate of the fatality rate of SARS-CoV-2 (i.e. ~3% to ~14%), these estimates are much lower than the percentage of deaths relative to recovered/discharged for closed cases (~21%).

My understanding is that the latter number should be considered the more accurate estimate of how deadly the contagion is since only the closed cases represent terminal states of an individual. If we introduce cases that are still ongoing or the population which has not contracted the disease then, to me, this seems misleading.

However, the majority of individuals and reporting I have seen use the former statistics and so I feel as if I am missing a key insight. I am hoping that the community could help clarify this for me.

Also, it was challenging to determine which forum would be the best for this question. If there is a better one, please let me know and I will repost at that location.

Thank you very much for your time and stay safe!

Comment: A major problem with COVID-19 data is the no one has any idea of the true prevalence. There is strong evidence that some (perhaps many) people who get infected recover without seeing doctors, much less getting admitted to hospitals. (These are thought to be mainly younger people without underlying conditions such as heart, lung, or kidney disease, and who do not have super-active immune systems that run amok and lead to conditions such as pneumonia), Naturally the death rate among the sickest victims who spend time in ICU on ventilators is much higher than for those with less severe cases.

Comment: I have been trying to track news reports of confirmed cases vs. deaths. Depending on location, percentages of deaths computed from these data mostly range from 1.5% to 3.5%. You are quite right that these death rates may underestimate the death rate among cases they count because some deaths are yet to come. As the pandemic progresses a higher percentage of actual deaths will be included and these rates may converge to some version of reality. But these rates are almost entirely for people treated in hospitals or otherwise known to the medical establishment.

Comment: You describe the background of your question, but what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is the "Fatality Rate"? IFR, CFR, and Mortality

There are a few clarifications needed to answer this question well. The "fatality rate" is not specific enough.

We typically speak of infection fatality rates (IFRs), case fatality rates (CFRs) and mortality rates.

- The IFR is the percentage of deaths among people infected with the
  disease;
- The CFR is the percentage of deaths among people who sought medical
  help and tested positive; and,
- The mortality rate is the percentage of the population which will die.

The IFR may be difficult to estimate without broad testing of the population.

The CFR is usually easier to measure since people feel symptoms, go to the doctor, and get tested. (They "opt in" to testing.) In the recent pandemic, however, even people with symptoms sometimes avoided going to the doctor, so the CFR may be biased higher -- because only people with severe symptoms go to the doctor. Since the CFR is conditional on being symptomatic (perhaps severely), we expect CFR > IFR.

Unless an entire population gets infected, we expect mortality rates to be lower than IFRs.

## Estimation of CFRs (and Maybe IFRs)

You looked at Worldometer's measure of deaths/resolved cases. Since most countries are not doing universal (nor near-universal) testing, this is an estimate of the CFR: people have to have symptoms to go get tested and thus be in the denominator.

However, there is also a time element at play. Early on in an epidemic/pandemic, some people are more susceptible to infection and death. Thus we will see those people get sick and die at rates greater than for the rest of the population. That makes this number likely to be an overestimate. We also would expect it to decrease as time goes on.

Some people look at a measure of deaths/total cases. This is surely an underestimate because some of those cases have not yet been resolved and it is likely some will result in death.

## Cross-Country Comparisons

If we look across countries, the picture seems to become more muddled: countries such as the US are reporting very high CFRs while places like South Korea report very low CFRs. The truth is that some of the countries (like South Korea) have tested widely. This makes their reported "CFR" much more like an IFR. Furthermore, you will see variation in their deaths/resolved cases metrics depending on their population demographics and if the virus is just starting to work through their vulnerable populations or not. We saw very high rates (near the 21% you mention) for deaths/resolved cases in the US and Italy early on because the infections in those countries hit older populations very hard early on. If you look at those numbers now, you will see they are closer to 5% to 7%.

## Current Estimates of SARS-CoV-2 IFR and CFR

Finally, what are the IFR and CFR for SARS-CoV-2? So far, it seems like the IFR is around 0.3%, though some work is now suggesting a number perhaps as high as 0.6%. The CFR has generally been 10x to 20x higher which agrees with over 85% of people having no or very mild symptoms (i.e. too mild to merit going to a doctor). That would put the CFR at 5% to 9% (using a 15x multiplier).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only fair answer is that it is complicated. What you want to say (e.g., fatality rate if infected vs. fatality rate if confirmed positive vs. fatality rate by cohort vs. expected population fatalities) makes a fairly big difference.

We can think of the percent of deaths vs closed cases as a reasonable upper bound on the case fatality rate (the fatality in confirmed cases). That is, it is reasonable to assume that the fatality rate in the open cases is not higher than the fatality rate in closed cases (this may not always be true — for example, if those recover usually do so quickly while fatalities usually take a long time — but it is likely reasonable for SARS-CoV-2 where the opposite appears to be true).

We can think of the percent of deaths vs all cases as the lower bound on the case fatality rate, since nothing can happen (from current cases) to lower that rate.

The true value likely falls somewhere in between the two, though *where* in between depends primarily on the speed of progression for fatalities and for recoveries. If every single case either died or recovered exactly 14 days after confirmation, the fatality rate vs closed cases would be a good estimate of the true case fatality rate (because it accurately measures the case fatality rate for cases that have hit 14 days). If every case that dies does so immediately after confirmation, but recovery takes an indeterminate amount of additional time, the fatality rate in all cases is accurate (because we can assume that all currently living cases will recover).

The reality is somewhere in between because we know that most cases that live beyond a certain point (say, 7 days, for example) are substantially more likely to survive. Then, the question becomes how to weight your cases to account for this difference in progression (to fatality or recovery) appropriately.

However, this neglects the prevalence of undiagnosed cases. The true infection fatality rate (the fatality rate in *all* infections, not just those that are diagnosed) requires an estimation of the infections that are undetected (e.g., asymptomatic carriers and those that skip testing) and the deaths that are not attributed to the disease (e.g., deaths before testing or those that die at home without ever going in).

In the case of SARS-CoV-2, the infection fatality rate is almost certainly lower than the case fatality rate. So, it can be argued (though I have not seen it publicly) that the fatality rate vs. all cases may *accidentally* be closer to the correct value **if** the undetected infections closely balance the fatalities that are still to come.

I don't think this answered your question directly (though, I am not sure what the actual question is), but I hope that it at least explains the complexity (particularly to the nearly stats-illiterate general public) in estimating and explaining the fatality rate.